# How do I change the html mark style using react?

Tags: reactjs

I have such an div element:

```
 <div className="rate" > 
       <mark className="rate-mark"> Rate : </mark>
       <mark className="val-mark" style={{color}}> {rate}</mark>
 </div>
```

where the color is a hook:

```
var green = "#0cb87f";
var red = "#ce2020";

const [color,setColor] = useState(green)
```

I'm trying to dynamically change the color like this :

```
if (response.getRate() < rate){
   setColor(red)
}else{
   setColor(green)
}
```

But in my case it turns out that the light is always green.I think the mark page element is just never updated.How can this be made to work?

Comment: Is this always false? `(response.getRate() < rate)`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I have observed values and these were cases not only false

Comment: I think you might need to show us a proof-of-concept example, e.g. a code sandbox example, since based on the code you've shared here I don't see how it wouldn't work.

Comment: keep in mind `color` is the font, `backgroundColor` is the highlight color.

Comment: I think your assumption is likely incorrect btw, and that `(response.getRate() < rate)` **is** always false.